# Get shop-name / URL with embedded app in shopify (app is iFramed)

Tags: javascript

I have built a dashboard in Javascript/React/node.js to sit within a shopify store owners admin page.

Each store owner will have their own data and dashboard, I am trying to get the shop name in the dashboard (found in the URL).

The dashboard is an iFrame of my dashboard that I am hosting.

Alternatively I have noticed when the authentication process begins when the user installs the app the domain is collected and stored, is there a way to capture this each time the store-owner is using the app? So I can try this from the server -> dashboard rather than dashboard -> server?

any help would be massively appreciated.

I have tried many many methods of trying to get the parent page's URL and data such as below:

None of them work they all return undefined or say 'localhost' is there anyway to capture this with Javascript?

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location)
            ? document.referrer
            : document.location.href;
parent.document.location
parent.window.document.location
parent.window.location
parent.document.location.href
```

There is a method of using sessions with cookies but if someone clears their cookies I think the app would need to be reinstalled.

Comment: An `iframe` is subject to the Same Origin policy, and can only access its parent if both are loaded from the same origin.

Comment: Right, I've got it, seems i'm in a bit of a pickle then.

Comment: how to get shopurl when the app is not iframed?